# Back button not working when placed in AppBar

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 app. I have added a basic page to my project, which automatically adds a back button:

```
<Button x:Name="backButton"
        Margin="39,59,39,20"
        Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
        Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

The button works fine. However, when I move this button to an AppBar, it doesn't work. The view doesn't go back to the previous page.
What is going wrong in the latter case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppBar isn't in the same namespace as the page and so the Command binding to the page's NavigationHelper property doesn't resolve. This is the case for any binding of the AppBar to the page.

You can fix this by setting the AppBar's DataContext to the page in page.Loaded

XAML

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" IsOpen="True">
        <Button x:Name="backButton"
            Margin="39,59,39,20"
            Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand}"
            Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

C#

```
public BasicPage1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;

    this.Loaded += BasicPage1_Loaded;
}

async void BasicPage1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bottomAppBar.DataContext = this;
}
```

--Rob

Comment: Worked for me. I tried it first in `navigationHelper_LoadState`  because that's where I build my data context from the navigation paramaters, but that didn't work. It had to go into the `Loaded` event handler. Note that you don't have to name the app bar, you can just use the page property `this.BottomAppBar`.

Comment: re: naming the app bar, I've found that sometimes I need to name the particular control, eg. "backButton", and assign the data context explicitly, as described, ie. `this.backButton.DataContext = this;`. I haven't got to the bottom of this.